# Fancontrol starts manually but fails as service

Tags: linux, debian, services, lm-sensors

When fancontrol is started from the terminal it works fine

```
# fancontrol
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...

Common settings:
  INTERVAL=2

Settings for /sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/pwm1:
  Depends on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.3/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/temp1_input
  Controls /sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/fan1_input
  MINTEMP=17
  MAXTEMP=53
  MINSTART=140
  MINSTOP=50
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=255

Settings for /sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/pwm3:
  Depends on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.3/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/temp1_input
  Controls /sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/device/fan2_input
  MINTEMP=17
  MAXTEMP=55
  MINSTART=140
  MINSTOP=50
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=255

Enabling PWM on fans...
Starting automatic fan control...
```

However when starting fancontrol as a service (at or after boot), it fails.

```
# service fancontrol start
[ ok ] Starting fan speed regulator: fancontrol.
# service fancontrol status
[FAIL] fancontrol is not running ... failed!
```

What is the difference between starting fancontrol as a service vs manually that would cause it to fail?

Debian Wheezy
Fancontrol initscript

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          fancontrol
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: fancontrol
# Description:       fan speed regulator
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/fancontrol
DESC="fan speed regulator"
NAME="fancontrol"
PIDFILE=/var/run/fancontrol.pid
CONF=/etc/fancontrol

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $CONF ] ; then
        if $DAEMON --check 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
            log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON
            log_end_msg $?
        else
            log_failure_msg "Not starting fancontrol, broken configuration file; please re-run pwmconfig."
        fi
    else
        if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
            log_warning_msg "Not starting fancontrol; run pwmconfig first."
        fi
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --oknodo --startas $DAEMON
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
```

Comment: Post here the initscript (/etc/init.d/fancontrol) so we can look what is happening during the boot start. Also post what OS you use.

Some quick ideas:

1) different ENV variables

2) sudo command somewhere inside the initscript && requiretty in sudo configuration

Comment: @Fiisch Im on Debian wheezy and ive added the fancontrol initscript.

Comment: Try to run `start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/fancontrol.pid --startas /usr/sbin/fancontrol` from your terminal and post results. Also try the same but first set your PATH to the same as is written in the initscript. And please post the output of `which fancontrol` from your bash session. :)

PS: Sorry for the delay. I had much work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel silly, should've investigated more. Here is the answer just incase I mess this up or anyone else has the same problem. Also, many thanks to @Fiisch for advice and pointing me in the right direction.

When starting fancontrol via `#service fancontrol start` or `#fancontrol`, the errors of /usr/sbin/fancontrol are not printed. Due to motherboard limitations, my sensors are defined as absolute paths. So I ran /usr/sbin/fancontrol. This causes the error

```
Configuration is too old, please run pwmconfig again
```

So I decided to take a look at /usr/sbin/fancontrol to see why. I found the cause at lines 302-307:

```
# Check for configuration change
if [ -z "$DEVPATH" -o -z "$DEVNAME" ]
then
    echo "Configuration is too old, please run pwmconfig again" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Its just a simple configuration change detector! since, I had specified the absolute paths for my sensors, not only was this not necessary, it was actually causing the error. So I just commented it out.

```
## Check for configuration change
#if [ -z "$DEVPATH" -o -z "$DEVNAME" ]
#then
#   echo "Configuration is too old, please run pwmconfig again" >&2
#   exit 1
#fi
```

That was it! fancontrol works perfectly now and starts at boot time.